# $_FILES superglobal array key is not what file.inc expects

Tags: forms, files

I'm trying to do some custom stuff with a file upload field via the form API. I call to `file_save_upload()` but it thinks that the upload is empty because it's examining `$_FILES['files']` but for some reason, my file is actually in `$_FILES['CSV_file']` even when the file I uploaded is not a csv.

How might files superglobal end up with a `CSV_file` array key?

UPDATE

So apparently the form array

```
$form['my_menu_csv'] = array(
  '#name' => 'CSV files',
  '#type' => 'file',
  '#title' => t('Choose a CSV file'),
  '#title_display' => 'invisible',
  '#size' => 22,
  '#theme_wrappers' => array(),
  '#weight' => -10,
);
```

was causing the field to have the following HTML:

```
<input type="file" id="edit-my-menu-csv" name="CSV file" size="22" class="form-file">
```

and apparently the files array goes like `$_FILES[$name]`, where $name = whatever the name attribute is in the HTML element. Makes sense! What doesn't make sense is why `file_save_upload()` expects to only ever encounter `$_FILES['files']` but the form API uses a custom field name. Is this a bug in the form API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's a bug.

$_FILES['files'] is hard-coded into [file_save_upload()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_save_upload/7).

I believe you need to change how you construct your `#name` property.  The [usage example in the Form API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#file) does it like this:

```
'#name' => 'files[' . implode('_', $element['#parents']) . ']',
```